# Which PR is responsible for a code line on GitHub?

Tags: github

Within any accessible GitHub repo and a given code segment (e.g. a function), how is it possible to see which commit or PR has led to it?

Comment: Well if you're using a modern IDE such as IntelliJ, the Git plugin there can show this information.

Comment: if you are using github web interface, go to any file and click "Blame" button in there . It will show you the  history of that file. Browse to the relevant section, for example to the function and you can see what all commits changed that section. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a file with annotations of which commits contributed by hitting the blame button on a file view.
[image: The top of a github file, with the 'Blame' button highlighted]

[image]